# create multiple java threads in a while loop depending on the number of inputs

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, loops

i am trying to write a java programm that is reading informations out of a database and creates for every row of the table a new thread. So i dont know how much threads i will need. so far i have this:

```
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
        pst = con.prepareStatement("select hostname, ipadress, vncpassword from infoscreens");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        int i=0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            i++;
            Thread tread[i]  = new Savescreenshots(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(2));
            tread[i].start();
        }
```

but the problem is that this isnt working. i need a possibility to create for each row in the table a new thread. dose anyone have an idea how to do that

thanks and greetings

Comment: You should provide more details, like: what is not working? Also you should consider using a thread pool, id you will have a lot of db entries.

Comment: what is not working. Can you please indicate that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a dynamically growing container for a set of unknown size - a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), for example:

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
while (rs.next()) {
    Thread tread  = new Savescreenshots(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(2));
    tread.start();
    threads.add(thread);
}
```

At this point, all `Thread` objects that your program created and started are elements of the `threads` list. You can enumerate them and do whatever else you were planning to do with them (e.g. wait for them to finish):

```
for (Thread thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}
```

Comment: Not strictly necessary. The OP may not need to keep references to the threads at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea sounds insane but what you could do, is using the SQL functionality in Java, to find out how many rows you currently have and then use that number to create your threads.

Comment: What about the data which is needed by the constructor of each thread? Or are you saying create a pool of threads first and then...?

Comment: Didn't go any further, because the idea is ludicrous. Why would you make a thread for each row in a database? You'll run out of memory very fast if you have too many rows to read.

Comment: What? Those are the requirements. It's no where stated that the number of rows is going to be huge? What if the application cannot be served to greater than N clients at a time. If the business requirements need the application has to wait until a few threads become free?

Comment: "i am trying to write a java programm that is reading informations out of a database and creates for every row of the table a new thread." For every row of the table a new thread is made. I don't think he'll reuse threads at all, more like read them at all times and keep reading, when new entries are made. If he used an ExecutorService maybe he could read some rows at a time, but his description doesn't seem to just read a few, but the whole thing all the time.

Comment: See what is he reading : hostname, ipadress, vncpassword. Perhaps there won't be too many rows ever. Perhaps he is making connections to the VNC hosts on each thread. In that case I don't think there should be too many rows in the db. I think I have used too many Perhaps.

Comment: Seems like a non-ludicrous idea to me too.  Multiple VNC connections, each served by a different thread. Normal.

Comment: He wants to read every Row of the Database Table. It's not normal to make a thread for each Row in this scenario. If he made multiple threads for people to access the Database Rows, that would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

try using just simple variable say t instead of array tread[i].
Also, creating a new thread for every row might fill out memory if number of rows is large.